# How can I tell if a user did mute me in chat?

Tags: support, chat

**How can I tell if a user did mute me in chat?**

Of recent, and out of curiosity, I began to wonder if this is possible.

I haven't read any thing specifying on this on the Help Center pages, nor searching for a similar question here has turned up anything.

Comment: Become a moderator.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I would if I could, no Mod Elections have taken place on the site where I have enough rep (Arqade) since I got here a year ago. And, according to some of Mods I talked to, one will not be taking place for a long time...

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Even if someone *tells* you they've muted you, they could be lying. Especially since engaging you defeats the whole purpose of muting.

Answer (score 6):

There's no direct way to check. The only place this is visible is the view you have of your *own profile* . You can see who *you* have ignored - not who other people have ignored

This is actually pretty good design since you'd be surprised at the stuff people pull off to get around being muted, from asking folks to relay messages, to using/abusing bots.

As such, the best way to get that information is to politely and apologetically ask if that's the case. If you don't get a response, chances are they really don't want to speak to you.

Comment: Or, you could ask another user to ask them, to increase the chances of a response.

Comment: If you feel you need to ask, its almost certain you're blocked. And that people do this is mentioned in my answer as being undesirable. IE... ehh, that's not what you usually want to do when blocked if you ever want to be unblocked

Comment: Also, ignores are per chat server, so one could invite them to a room on a different chat server.

Comment: True, and then they can ignore that invite and then you know too. Or... IDK. Just figure anyone who isn't talking to you dosen't want to talk to you

Comment: So wait. I would have to sing put and view my profile?

Comment: You can see who *you* have ignored - not who other people have ignored